# Don't allow specific apps to show their windows

Tags: macos

I'm looking for an ideal productivity timer and while I cannot find it, I decided to make it by myself. First of all I love the feature to block specific apps while timer is ticking (like in [Flow](https://itunes.apple.com/app/flow-break-and-focus-timer/id1423210932): when I try to open SomeDistractingApp, timer immediately hides SomeDistractingApp's window), but I have no idea how to do this and where to start. Can you give me an advice?

Comment: In "app is still working in background, when I click on it's icon in dock, timer immediately hides app's window", is Flow the app and the timer and does it hide its own window? Do you want to hide the windows or the app (Command-H)?

Comment: @Willeke when timer is working, if I try to open Safari (and if Safari in my blacklist) timer should not allow Safari's window to show

Comment: It looks like Flow hides the app when it is activated. Take a look at `NSRunningApplication` and the notifications of `NSWorkspace`.